# What is the difference between 描【か】く and 描【えが】く?

Tags: kanji, readings, kanji-choice

I believe the two forms of [to draw](https://jisho.org/search/to%20draw) are 描{か}く and 描{えが}き. What are the differences between them? Which one is used more commonly?

Comment: Do you mean 描【えが】く?

Comment: @jarmanso7 I meant the 描{か}く form listed on Jisho.

Comment: I mean 描【えが】く instead of 描【えが】き

Comment: I see now. I did not, but curious about the difference between those.

Comment: https://eigobu.jp/magazine/egaku#heading-95620

Comment: Greg, what sense of _"to draw"_ do you mean? [There are 41 distinct senses in the Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/draw), for instance. Regarding the Japanese, it seems like you're at the very beginning stages of your studies. All "dictionary form" verbs end in _-u_, while many (but not all) stem / noun / gerund forms of verbs end in _-i_. From your question, 描【えが】く and 描【えが】き are the same verb, just in different conjugation forms -- like English _"draw"_ and _"drew"_ are different conjugations of the same verb. Separately, that Jisho.org page doesn't have any 描【えが】き entry...?

Comment: Thanks @EiríkrÚtlendi the conjugation was where I was confused. It sounds like 描{えが}く and 描{えが}き mean the same thing? To jarmanso7's point, I see now that 描{が}くfrom my original post is an incorrect spelling.

Comment: かく and えがく can both be written 描く. えがき is a conjugation of えがく.

Comment: Thanks Leebo. Do both forms かく and えがく maintain the same meaning?

Comment: btw why this question is down voted ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, take a look at [this related discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/8hnd8v/when_to_use_%E6%8F%8F%E3%81%8F%E3%81%88%E3%81%8C%E3%81%8F_vs_%E6%8F%8F%E3%81%8F%E3%81%8B%E3%81%8F_reading/dyl2cu5/) in reddit, in particular to the following passage:

> [...] As for the pronunciations of 描くI believe they are fairly interchangeable, but えがく is used more for artistic sketching or 'picturing' and かく for drawing diagrams.

Comment: Good find, I'll commit to knowing this distinction.